# DirectX — is there an analogue of DirectDraw surface Flip()?

Tags: c++, directx, directdraw

I'm building an application that is drawing an anaglyph (stereoimage) on 200 Hz screen based on two provided pictures (NOT 3D model). So speed integity of redrawing is very important. I've achieved the best results with DirectDraw surfaces and their Flip() (switching current surface's image to secondary one):

```
(void) lpddsPrimary->Flip(nullptr, DDFLIP_WAIT);
```

But DirectDraw is very outdated and I look for a way to reimplement this functionality based on modern DirectX libraries. But I really don't want to create a quad, draw picture as it's texture, calculate 3D projection matrices just to output 2D images.

I would be really greatful for any snippet of how this can be possibly done with DirectX. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I couldnt understand why directdraw is outdated. Use direct3d for this purpose myself just for the features it provides, but the principle is almost the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purposes you can use DXGI and avoid D3D completely.  You don't say how you get the data into the backbuffer, but DXGI allows you to create a swapchain, flip it (Present), and access the surfaces (e.g. lock them - it's called Map now).  For 3D you need the "1" versions e.g. DXGISwapChain1.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205075(v=vs.85).aspx.

Note that DXGISwapChain1 is a subclass of DXGISwapChain, and some vital methods such as GetBuffer are in the base interface.

Comment: Thanks! But what about compatibility? Program needs to be run on WinXP end machines.

Comment: Then you can't use modern DirectX libraries.